# Applying Aggregate Functions On all Columns

Tags: sql, database, db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an Employee table with Salary. I want to list Salary - Avg(Salary) for every Employees. Can someone please help me with the SQL query for the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using window functions:

```
select e.*,
       (salary - avg(salary) over ()) as diff
from employees e;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inline view to return a single row with the average salary. and join that row back to employee table.

Something like this:

```
 SELECT e.emp_id
      , e.salary 
      , e.salary - a.avg_salary
   FROM employee e
  CROSS
   JOIN ( SELECT AVG(t.salary) AS avg_salary
            FROM employee t
        ) a
  ORDER BY e.emp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple other variations; the others already posted should serve the purpose quite well -- assuming we've all correctly inferred the desired output, given no DDL nor sample data, nor the expected output from the given inputs.

If there is no requirement to include the averaged salary [as the average over all rows] in addition to the calculated difference, then the following [shown with an optional casting to a decimal result] uses a scalar subselect to get the value to subtract from each employee salary:

```
select emp.*                                 
     , dec( salary - ( select avg(salary)  
                       from employee_table )
          , 11, 0 ) as saldif               
from employee_table as emp
```

Or to use the averaged salaries in both the difference and as a column by itself, then again the scalar subselect, but made available for lateral reference in the [explicitly joined-to] subquery; again, optional casting for decimal results:

```
select x.*                                      
from table                                      
  ( select avg(salary)                          
    from employee_table                         
  ) as a ( avgsal )                             
cross join lateral                              
  ( select emp.*                                
         , dec( salary - avgsal , 11 ) as saldif
         , dec( avgsal          , 11 ) as salavg
    from employee_table as emp                  
  ) as x
```

Answer (score 0):

other solution ;)

```
 with avgsalary as (
 select avg(salary) avgsal  from employee_table  
 )
 select emp.*, case when emp.salary  is null then cast(null as decimal) else round(emp.salary - avgs.avgsal, 2) end as diffsal, avgs.avgsal                                   
 from employee_table as emp cross join  avgsalary avgs
```

Answer (score 0):

And even another variation:

```
with EmpAvg (avgSalary)
     as ( SELECT avg( salary ) from employee_table )
select e.*, a.avgSalary,
      (e.salary - a.avgSalary) as diffAvg
from employee_table e cross join EmpAvg a
```

There may be many forms of queries that can give equivalent results. (Although I left off casting the calculated values, so not **exactly** equal result values.)